# Can you connect other routers to Google Nest Wifi and have them extend the network similar to a mesh config?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, mesh-networking, google-wifi

#### tl;dr:

- Can another wifi router be used to extend GoogleNest? (e.g. via Ethernet cable).
- Could it behave as a mesh? (aka use same network id and have devices easily hop between acces points)
- If yes, what are the drawbacks to just getting the Google Wifi Points?

#### Context

My family lives in a long house and the range of just one wifi point was not enough as such they have 3 wifi routers equaly distributed around the house and connected by ethernet cables. Each router has a different wifi name, e.g. wifi1, wifi2, wifi3
Current problems with the existing setup:

1. While going around the house many times you're connected to wrong endpoint and have to manually switch between endpoints.
2. Annoying to configure port forwarding for their security cameras, and in case of resets they are not able to set it up again. Would be nice to have easy & safe remote admin feature.
3. Annoying to setup wifi for users (each user needs to configure 3 wifi networks).
4. Wifi bandwith is ~80 MBytes/s while they have gigabit speedfrom ISP via fiber.

#### Current battle plan

Currently thinking to either:

1. Daisy chain the routers (aka connect routers in bridge mode via the ethernet cable), hope to solve problems 1 & 3. Check for remote admin options for problem 2, & manually set-up channels to sqeeze a bit more bandwith (4).
2. Get google nest wifi & daisy chain existing routers, hopefully solve 1, 2, 3 & possibly 4 where the google nest wifi has range
3. Get google nest wifi & 2 access points, solve 1,2,3,4 but at extra cost
4. Get an alternative wifi6 router from ISP (but might remain with problem #2, as possibly can't remotely configure) . Options include:

   1. TP-Link Archer AX10
   2. FIBERHOME SR1041Y
   3. HUAWEI K562E
   4. ZTE H3601

I am happy with my Google Nest Wifi in my apartment, especially reg the ease of configuration, speed tests and alerts it provides in the app. That's why I thought to try to include it in the new setup.

I'm not an expert with networks, but can configure a router & fw ports so feel free to include any solutions that you think would work best for a large house with ~10-20 devices connected on average (60 devices connected at peek). If needed I can also look at changing firmwares if it gives beter results.

#### Docs I'm currently reading

- [IEEE_802.11r fast Base Station transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11r-2008)
- [IEEE 802.11s mesh networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11s)
- [Wifi roaming for apple devices](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202628)